# How to specify English is the only language when using TTS in Kotlin

Tags: text-to-speech

I am using a Huawei android phone and Chinese is the default language. In writing an app (in Android Studio with Kotlin), the Text-to-Speech is speaking the English words in English but the numerals in Chinese.

Although I specify the "setLanguage(Locale("ENGLISH", "US")", the numerals are still spoken in Chinese, only English words are spoken in English.
How can I make the whole sentence is spoken in English including the numerals?

Comment: TTS isn't part of Kotlin.  It's part of several platforms/OSes kotlin can run on, but there's going to be different APIs on each.  YOu need to specify what library or platform you're using.  I know it's probably Android's default TTS system, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks Gabe.  I am using Android Studio to build the app. I dont know how to force the app  (? or the phone) to read the sentence in English including the numerals.  One more thing, the English word "and" is spoken as "a" "n" "d" !

Comment: That's commonly how TTS apps react to words they don't know, especially in languages they don't know.  Post your actual code that uses the TTS engine.

Comment: Right off the back, I notice you're passing in "ENGLISH" as the language.  That's a language code, it should be "en".  Or just use Locale.US.  Also note the user of the phone will need to have downloaded english-us TTS data, they may not have that by default

Comment: The actual code:
override fun onInit(status: Int) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                       
            val result = tts!!.setLanguage(Locale("ENGLISH", "US"))

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "The Language specified is not support")
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initialization Failed")
        }
    }

Comment: Gabe.  My problem solved. Changing "English" to "en" works fine.  The whole sentence including the numerals is now spoken in English.  Thank you.